Non-Local Causality - The Piston
A free particle is inside a box of length $L$ with a movable piston at the end. The piston is attached to two plates facing each other and a ball is fired at the first plate.
Now assume that all impacts are elastic, the ball will first displace the piston inward of $\delta L$, it will then bounce off the second plate, and will come out with the same initial energy. However, if the particle inside the box reaches the piston before the second bounce, the ball will come out of the system with a non-zero energy difference.

Now suppose that Alice wants to send the result of a coin-flip to Bob, which is on the side of the piston and is continuously sending balls to the first plate monitoring the energy. If the result is tails, Alice puts a particle in the box, which after some time will hit the piston, making Bob's detector click due to the energy difference being non-zero.
However, according to quantum mechanics, the particle inside the box is in a superposition of energy states $\hat H|n\rangle = \frac{n^{2}\pi^{2}\hbar^{2}}{2mL^{2}} |n\rangle$, and as soon as the first ball bounce takes place, the box is already shorter by $\delta L$, thus increasing the energy of the particle instantaneously. Then, by conservation of energy, the bouncing ball will also suddenly change its energy and Bob will immediately detect the click as soon as Alice gets tails, apparently receiving 1 bit of information instantly.
Now, because of causality this cannot happen, but I fail to see where this example goes wrong, why would Bob fail to detect a click as soon as Alice puts a particle in the box?

I hate to be the one to tell you, but everything in this example is classical mechanics. And there is no requirement that a particle Alice places inside a box have the kind of superposition you imagine. Instead, all she needs to do to send a bit to Bob is to fire a particle towards the piston. Note that nothing nonlocal occurs in such scenario, as there is a classical compression wave associated with this. Causality is never compromised.

If you have a system where the state of one particle affects the potential felt by a second particle, then you cannot solve the time-independent SE for only the second particle and expect that to work. You must solve the time-dependent SE for the two coupled particles.

But how are the two particles coupled? What if the box is one light-year long and is a perfect shielder, the outside ball would still make the box shorter immediately affecting the energy of the particle inside, right?

First things, one should distinguish different notions of causality and locality. I will use the following notions.

Causality: causes precede their effects.

Locality: there is no physical influence faster than light.


Classical mechanics:
Now, to your thought experiment. I do not understand what exactly you mean when you introduce quantum mechanics into the picture. But I think the main points were already contained in your classical presentation. Classical mechanics is causal in the sense that causes precede their effects (Assuming the right orientation of the Entropic arrow of time). However, classical mechanics is not local in the sense that no causal influence exists that is faster than light. Take, for example, Newtonian gravity. If you move a massive object according to Newtonian gravity, this will have an immediate impact on the gravitational potential throughout the universe. Of course, the change is so small that it would be unnoticeable for all practical purposes (The gravitational force decreases with $\frac{1}{r^2}$). But in principle, there is such an influence. This does not violate causality.
Special relativity:
Now, in special relativity, the causal structure is only a partial order. I.e., there are spacetime points $(t_1, \vec x_1)$, $(t_2, \vec x_2)$ where there is no fact on which of them was first. Therefore, combining Causality with Lorentz invariance (Causality should hold in all Lorentz frames) more or less leads to locality. This does not mean that special relativity is incompatible with non-locality (it is, in fact, not).
Your thought example would most likely violate locality. An even simpler example would be an incompressible rod between Alice and Bob. So, what is the moral of the thought experiment?
The message is that incompressible rigid bodies are an idealization only valid in the non-relativistic regime. Real, physical objects are made out of atoms; thus, they are never really rigid. Further, Newtonian gravity is not compatible with special relativity (this led to the development of general relativity).
When dealing with velocities way below the speed of light, we can do some idealization. E.g., the speed of sound in water may be treated as infinite compared to the speed of sound in air in some effective description. But fundamentally, it is not.
When the particle hits the piston in your example, the piston would not extend instantly, but there would be a pressure wave going through the piston at a speed below the speed of light.
On quantum mechanics:
Quantum mechanics is indeed a non-local theory. This is a consequence of Bell's theorem. However, this kind of non-locality is different from the classical one. While the gravitational force decreased with distance, the non-local effects of quantum mechanics have been measured for distances larger than $100\, \text{km}$.
However, this kind of non-locality does not allow sending signals faster than light.
Imagine the following simplification: Alice and Bob each have a black box that takes input parameters $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, and returns an $0,1$-output $Z_1$ and $Z_2$, respectively. For a given choice of $\alpha_1$, and $\alpha_2$, the probability for Alice and Bob to get the same result $Z_1 = Z_2$ is given by $\sin^2(\alpha_1- \alpha_2)$. But the marginal distributions are always $50/50$. Note, $\alpha_1- \alpha_2$ is a non-local quantity. The joint probability is non-local, but nothing Alice can do affects Bob's marginal probabilities. Therefore, Alice cannot send a signal to Bob.
